# Client to send SOAP request

Tags: c#, web-services, request

Trying to create a C# client (will be developed as a Windows service) that sends SOAP requests to a web service (and gets the results).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ISca.png)

It breaks

```
HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: The remote server returned an error: (500)
>   Internal Server Error.

Comment: This just means that the server has a misconfiguration or some other problem that prevented it from fulfilling the request. Your web service client could be doing things right. Do you have access to the server? Also, does this service contain a wsdl?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, your backend has found some kind of problem in your SOAP request body, which is indicated by the 500 server error return code.

Usually, when working with SOAP end points, you would take the WSDL and generate a client in C# for it (using Visual Studio). Does your SOAP endpoint react to adding a `?wsdl` after the request URL? Like so: `https://soap.server.com/MyEndPoint?wsdl`.

After getting such a `wsdl` file, you can use that to generate a C# client for this endpoint, e.g. using Service References, or the `wsdl.exe` tool. Unfortunately, things changed between .NET 4.0 and 4.5, so knowing your targeted runtime would also be needed for a full answer.